# Firebase A/b testing remote config not working in release build

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I am new in Firebase A/B testing with remote config. I create parameter(SplashAds) in remote config with default value 0. When i create experiment in A/B testing for retention day 1, i change value of parameter (SplashAds) 1. For day 1 retention when i execute app in debug mode from android studio i got SplashAds value 1 for day 1 retention. Its fine but when i used release build then i got default value 0 means A/B testing not working in release build. Please help me guys
here the code for get

```
 mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(3600)
            .build();
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        long SplashAdsDisable = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getLong("SplashAdsDisable");
                        long Interstitialadsclick = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getLong("Interstitialadsclick");
                        long RewardsAdsClick = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getLong("RewardsAdsClick");
                        long WhatsWebAdsDisable = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getLong("WhatsWebAdsDisable");
                        long Homescreennativeadsdisable = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getLong("Homescreennativeadsdisable");
                        long ExitadsDisable = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getLong("ExitadsDisable");                    
                    }
                }
            });
```